# I have two slides of icons and how to move the icons to next slide when the icons are overflowing in first slide at different resolutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have attached the sample problem here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rucsuw

When the screen size reduces the icons overflow out of the container and I want the overflowing items to get displayed in the next slide

This is how it is displayed in bigger screen size

[image: icons before overflowing]

When the window size is smaller it overflows like this

[image: icons in smaller resolution]

I want to display the icons which are overflowing in the next slide.

How can I calculate and move the overflowing items to next slide?

It should be responsive too. Any idea how to implement this ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can give `overflow-y: scroll` to the element or change `height: 40vh;` to `min-height: 40vh;`